# CIStraightenFilter returns a blank image for large input

Tags: swift, core-image

I'm trying to straighten an image on iOS using the core image `CIStraightenFilter` filter. The input image may be very large, for example 8192 x 4096 pixel. When I run the filter on a large image, the result image is produced, but the raw values are all 0, so the image is black/transparent. This does not happen for smaller images, say 1024 x 512.

My code is:

```
func straighten(image: UIImage, by rotationAngle: Measurement<UnitAngle>) -> CIImage?
{
    guard let ciImg = CIImage(image: image) else { return nil }
    let rotationInRadians = CGFloat(rotationAngle.converted(to: .radians).value)
    
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIStraightenFilter")!
    filter.setValue(ciImg, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(rotationInRadians, forKey: kCIInputAngleKey)
            
    return filter.outputImage
}
```

When I debug I can see that both `image` and `ciImg` are valid (if I click the preview I can see the image). The resulting `CIImage` is not `nil`, but doesn't have any color information.

Questions:

- Is the any limitation as to the image size I can pass into a filter?
- What can I do now for large images?

**EDIT**
Upon request in the comments: After applying the filter, I'm simply creating a `CGImage` (and then an `UIImage`) from the filter's result. That image is then also blank.

```
if let ciStraightened = straighten(image: inputImage, by: Measurement<UnitAngle>(value: angle, unit: .degrees)
{
    let ctx = CIContext(options:nil)
    if let cgImg = ctx.createCGImage(ciStraightened, from: ciStraightened.extent)
    {
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImg)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hallo Thorsten. Can you please show what you do with the image afterward? How are you using it? Are you rendering it with a `CIContext`?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I have updated the question with the requested information. The strange thing is that if I place a breakpoint on the `let ctx = CIContext...` line, and inspect the `ciStraightened` variable pressing the "eye"-button, the image is blank already, so the problem doesn't seem to be the code after filtering the image, but the filter itself. As said in the question, the code above works fine for smaller images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask a `CIContext` for its `inputImageMaximumSize()`. In my test this was 8192 x 8192, so barely matching the example size you provided. *But* it might be the case that Core Image needs to create intermediate buffers during the computation that might need to be larger than the input (this should be the case for `CIStraightenFilter`). And I imagine that this would exceed the above limit. So you probably need to scale down the image first.

By the way: When you use Quick Look to inspect a `CIImage` in the Debugger, Xcode will render that image for you *in that moment* using a `CIContext`. Up until it is rendered, a `CIImage` is just a "recipe" for creating an image. That's why it also appears empty when you inspect it in the debugger.

Comment: Hm, sounds reasonable, esp. since the straighten filter scales the image up. But what if I want the output of the filter to be 8192 x 4096? I'd have to a) calculate in advance the size of the result and scale down the source so that rotation does not exceed 8192 x 8192 (how would I do that?) and b) I'd have to scale the result up to 8192 x 4096 again, which reduced quality.

Comment: Maybe you could use a `VNDetectHorizonRequest` to get the angle that you need to rotate the image and then use Core Graphics or Accelerate (on the CPU) to rotate the image in full resolution...

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I actually implemented my own straightening algorithm using `UIImage` only. Quick enough for what I need :-)